Simulate hall voltage as a function of temperature in LTspice
I'm trying to simulate how temperature affects voltage sensitivity in my hall sensor from LTspice. How do I make use of this equation to get my correct output? Any feedback will help, thank you. I should be getting a somewhat downwards linear graph.




You can incorporate the temperature sensitivity into your behavioral voltage sources. The below shows the data for 2.0V fitted to a quadratic.

I took the 2.0V data from this paper which also appears to be the source of your images.

Hi, thank you for help. But may I know how you achieve the formula for the behavioral voltage?

I fit the data in the table at the linked paper to a quadratic (actually I first tried a higher order polynomial but quadratic turned out to be quite good enough). That found the three parameters. How you do that is up to you, but even Excel can do it (eg. minimize the total of the error^2 at the given data points as a cost function), and there are probably online methods.

Here is an article on temperature dependent devices in LT spice:
https://maker.pro/forums/resources/managing-temperature-in-ltspice.18/
If you could reduce your graph to a first order polynomial fit (y=m*x+b) then you could just introduce that in your equation that describes the hall sensor.
